# WPF Datagrid: Binding is not working for DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

i'm faily new in WPF and got a problem with a binding not refreshing the UI.

If i open the window, the datagrid fills as it should. I have an object with refences to 2 other that where compared beforehand, named "Original" and "Vergleicher".
The method "MenuItem_OnClick" copies the value vom "Vergleicher" to "Original". In the binded list this works, i can see the changed values in the debugger, but the UI ignores it.

Set the datacontext in window:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

The actual datagrid:

```
<TabItem Header="Unterschiede" Visibility="{Binding UiLeistungUnterschiedlich, 
            Converter={StaticResource EmptyListHiddenConverter}}" Selector.Selected="OnTabSelected">
  <Border Style="{StaticResource DropBorderStyle}">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding UiLeistungUnterschiedlich}" 
      SelectionChanged="GridHalter_SelectionChanged" SelectedIndex="0"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserAddRows="False">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <other Datagridtextcolumns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Straße">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type abrechnungen:HalterVergleich}">
              <StackPanel Background="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True, ConverterParameter=Strasse, 
                 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundColorConverter}}">
                <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                  <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="In Halter übernehmen" Click="MenuItem_OnClick" Tag="Strasse"/>
                  </ContextMenu>
                </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Original.Strasse, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Vergleicher.Strasse, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
              </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>         

      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </Border>
</TabItem>
```

The Border is used to apply a Dropshadow.

The copy method:

```
  private void MenuItem_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
        if (!(sender is MenuItem {DataContext: HalterVergleich vergleich} item))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!vergleich.Setzen(item.Tag?.ToString(), Setzen.ZuOriginal))
        {
            return;
        }
        
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UiLeistungUnterschiedlich));
  }
```

Sidenote: If anyone knows a way to avoid the use of "Tag" (to call "MenuItem_OnClick") and "ConverterParameter" with explizit values, i would gladly hear it.

Comment: You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged so the element you modify can notify that they changed [check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). In the code you showed you notify that the list changed but this is not the case (a reset notification on the list would probably work though still incorrect).

Comment: I am implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. That gave me the OnPropertyChanged method.

Comment: You are implementing it but on the wrong object. Use it on the Original object (best way) or notify that the list changed by sending a collectionchanged or reset notification (check [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=net-5.0) but in your case if you only modify the `Original object, it's overkill`).